# Postgres jsonb_insert array

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-json

I am trying to construct a query that returns an array of customer carts and all of their items, e.g.

**Tables:**

**cart**: `id`, `customer_id`

**item**: `cart_id`, `price`, `brand`

**Desired JSON result example:**

```
[{
  "id": 1, "customer_id": 1,
  "items": [{
    "price": 14.50, "brand": "Coke"
  }]
}]
```

Failing SQL Query (Testable here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0ef54/1):

```
SELECT jsonb_insert(to_jsonb(c.*), 'items', array(
  SELECT to_jsonb(i.*)
  FROM item i
  WHERE i.cart_id = c.id
)
FROM cart c
```

How can one achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds as if you are looking for an aggregation:

```
select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(c)||jsonb_build_object('items', i.items))
from cart c 
  join (
    select cart_id, jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(i) - 'cart_id') as items
    from item i
    group by cart_id
  ) i on i.cart_id = c.id;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f1bcaa01d2928d509b901e513bf268da)

Comment: Tried that, threw an error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0ef54/2

Comment: @Werner: sorry, forgot the alias. See my edit

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(c.*) || 
 jsonb_build_object
 (
  'items', 
  (select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(i.*) - 'cart_id') from item i where c.id = i.cart_id)
 )
) from cart c;
```

- Demo

```sql
create temporary table item (cart_id integer, price numeric, brand text);
create temporary table cart (id integer, customer_id integer);
insert into item values (1, 10, 'skoda'),(1, 11, 'ford'), (1, 12, 'opel'); 
insert into item values (2, 20, 'skoda'),(2, 21, 'ford'), (2, 22, 'opel'); 
insert into cart values (1, 1), (2, 2);

select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(c.*) || jsonb_build_object(
 'items', (select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(i.*) - 'cart_id') from item i where c.id = i.cart_id)
)) from cart c;
```

- Result:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "items": [
      {
        "brand": "skoda",
        "price": 10
      },
      {
        "brand": "ford",
        "price": 11
      },
      {
        "brand": "opel",
        "price": 12
      }
    ],
    "customer_id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "items": [
      {
        "brand": "skoda",
        "price": 20
      },
      {
        "brand": "ford",
        "price": 21
      },
      {
        "brand": "opel",
        "price": 22
      }
    ],
    "customer_id": 2
  }
]
```